# How to instantiate a class using reflection and access class method (no interface)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface, system.reflection

I have a C# solution with 3 projects.

1. Windows Form Application
2. Windows Library Module 1 (frmSearch, frmDetail)
3. Windows Library Module 2 (frmSearch, frmDetail)

Module 1 and Module 2 has two forms each (as shown above). So what I want to do is from Module 2 I need to get `Module1.frmDetail`, then Instantiate the class and then access its constructor so I can pass a parameter.

The problem is that I don't have an interface of Module1.frmDetail (don't know if I need it), here is my actual code from Module2.frmSearch:

```
// Use Reflection to load Module1.frmDetail
if(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() != null)
{
  System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Module1.frmDetail");
  if(a != null)
  {
    System.Type type = a.GetType("Module1.frmDetail");
    var frm = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // here i want to pass a parameter to the constructor???

  }
}
```

Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: Module2 obviously knows that Module1 exists and that it has a type named "frmDetail", otherwise you wouldn't be able to hard-code that name into your Reflection code.  If that's the case, why isn't Module1 referencing Module2 and just creating the instance normally and dispensing with Reflection altogether?

Comment: Module1.frmDetail is the name of a type, not the name of an assembly.

Comment: Use version of [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) which passes parameters to constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an overload of [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.100%29) that chooses the constructor to call based on the parameters you pass it.